# Turning off auto complete in Google Sheets formulas

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

**Anytime I want to delete anything within a Google Sheets formula, I have to fight the program, because it desperately wants to "fix" my mistakes.**

Say I want to delete a bracket, it keeps adding it until I have deleted it two or three times. If I edit cell names (for example from `L18` to `L17`) it often adds the old number (resulting in a `L187`). Or it deletes the newly added number (result: `L1`). I have turned off auto-complete under 'Tools'. Is there any other way to fix this problem?

Using Firefox, just in case it's a browser problem instead of a Google Sheets problem.

Comment: This isn't happening to me. Have you tried to use another web browser?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately **it is a bug** that has lately appeared in the sheets and has **nothing to do with the auto-complete under 'Tools'**.
You cannot just *"turn it off"*.

Please use the `Help` menu to send a report to Google. *(the more the people to send, the quicker to be fixed)*

[image: How to report a bug in Google Sheets]

Comment: Welcome. 
Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.